# vba add shapes (stars) in function of an excel cell's integer

Tags: vba, integer, ms-office, shapes

I have a column "I" on a spreadsheet that gives an int from 1 to 5. In function of the integer/ranking over 5, I manage to display stars within the cell next to the integer:

```
Dim x As Integer, Cel As Range, Plg As Range
Dim y As Integer, etoile As Shape
Dim shp As Shape

With mysheet
    Set Plg = .Range("I" & startLine & ":I" & nbLines)

    For Each Cel In Plg
        y = 5
        For x = 1 To Cel.Value
            If Cel > 0 Then
        Set stars= .Shapes.AddShape(msoShape5pointStar, Cel.Left + y, Cel.Top + 5, 6, 6)
        y = y + 10
        stars.Line.Visible = msoFalse
        stars.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 13
            End If
        Next x
    Next Cel
End With
```

But as I use a program that refresh my column I and the integer I'm looking for a way to remove the stars I created before and then applied the new ranking/number of stars.

I tried  stuff like that before my code:

```
For Each shp In mysheet.Shapes
    If shp.Type = msoShapeTypeMixed Then shp.Delete
Next shp
```

Without great success...
Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this, please:

```
   Dim sh As Worksheet, st As Shape
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
     For Each st In sh.Shapes
        If st.Type = 1 And left(st.Name, 7) = "5-Point" Then st.Delete
     Next
```

You can also name the stars when created.Something like

```
'your existing code
'
Set stars= .Shapes.AddShape(msoShape5pointStar, Cel.Left + y, Cel.Top + 5, 6, 6)
       y = y + 10
 stars.Name = "MyStar" & "somethin else" '(maybe the Cel.Addres and use it in a similar way to delete only specific ones)
'your existing code
```

Then delete the shapes having the first 6 characters like "MyStar", or whatever you like...

If you need to selectively delete them, you can also determine their `TopLeftCell` address and delete according to this one.

Comment: Yes you got it sir ! Thanks the first one worked perfectly

Comment: @Pierre_CM: Glad I could help! But it would be good to also explore the rest of suggestions. Just in order to better understand and learn VBA... :)

Comment: I actually debug with the first one and checked all the properties of the object (name + adresses). So it actually helped me to get the points I missed and you suggested with both solutions !